# How to find out about docker image updates via commandline

Tags: docker, version, updates, dockerhub, docker-image

I use Docker 17.04.0-ce on Ubuntu 16.04.

Some month ago I pulled the docker image »busybox« using »docker pull busybox«. By default docker will use the »latest« tag for this.

When I list all available images it will list this image with a tag and ID:

```
> docker images 
REPOSITORY  TAG       IMAGE ID        CREATED         SIZE
busybox     latest    7968321274dc    3 months ago    1.11MB
```

As far as I know the tag »latest« may be treated the same as »master« in Git. So I would like to know: did something change since I pulled this image the last time? Is my local »latest« version up to date with the »latest« version on Docker Hub?

To use the git comparison again: Git would tell me that my local branch is behind the remote branch by »x« commits.

I tried `docker search busybox`, but this does not show any information like tags or creation date.

**Question 1:** How do I find out about newer docker images via commandline?

**Question 2:** How can I list all tags of an repository via commandline?

PS: On Docker Hub I can see all tags of the »busybox« repo and that the »latest« tag was updated/created „1 month ago“: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/busybox/tags/

```
Tag Name    Compressed Size    Last Updated
latest      678 KB             a month ago
```

So there indeed is a difference to my local image, which was created „3 months ago“. The only way to tell the difference seems to be the date however.